# UITextView issue when moved to another view during editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, xcode7

I have a `UITextView` in which I have set the codes to raise the view while keyboard appears. The problem is that ***while I am editing the TextView(while keyboard is visible) if I am clicking a button to redirect to another view, I am seeing the keyboard in another view for 1 second and then it disappears*** . Can anyone please tell me how it is coming and please help me removing that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**
 Keyboard hides with animation and it takes a little bit of time. You should hide keyboard before navigating to other view.
You can resign first responder when view will disappear.

**Objective C**

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{ // Add this function in your ViewController 

       [self.YourTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) { // Add this function in your ViewController 
    self.YourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Saqib Omer. Thanks to all of you who tried to help me. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

While redirecting to SecondView

You first need to resign your textView.

using

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

write below line in `viewWillDissapear` delegate method of the `viewController`(as  Lefteris suggested):

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Or

If you have single textview then,

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: You should do this on the viewWillDissapear delegate method of the viewcontroller. And not you should stick with endEditing instead of resigning first responder, as it covers all firstResponders

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Happy coding